# How to perform system identification of a mobile robot using white box approach?

Tags: mobile-robot, identification

Why isn't there much research going into the extraction of inertial and frictional values?

Is there any standardized approach?

Edit:
I will give a sample application! Say if we want to implement a computed torque controller to solve the problem of path tracking. I want to have all the dynamic parameters, so that the physical constraints such as maximum motor and gearbox torques are considered.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Pradheep Krishna, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched, what you found & what you expected to find. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and use the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: What is your application? What are you trying to do? Inertial values should be fundamental to any system identification because they determine the force/motion relationship. Please *edit your question* to clarify what you're asking about.